# C - accessing 2D array trough function doesn't work, crash

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to do calculation with a 2D matrix. Why does this crash without an error?

Code:

```
int main (void)
{
    int myArray[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{5,4,3}};
    int height = 2;
    int width = 3;

    modifyArray( (int**)myArray,height, width);

}

void modifyArray(int **array, int height1, int width1)
{

    int result;

    for(i=0;i<height1;i++) 
    {
        for(j=0;j<width1;j++)
        {
          result = (**((array+i*3)+j));
          printf("%d", result)
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please also give your error/compile message :)

Comment: Please post code that actually compiles! What is `modifyArray()` supposed to do? It does not modify an array.

Comment: It doesn't give any errors. It just crashes. Well It should do some calculations with the var result. Nothing more. But it already crashes now, so I think it is useless to give an entire chunk of code of pure math that doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the function treats the array passed as a 1-D array of `int` your declaration can be simplified to this.

```
#include <stdio.h>                        // <<--- include

void modifyArray(int *array, int height1, int width1)
{
    int i, j, result;                     // var declarations
    for(i=0;i<height1;i++) 
    {
        for(j=0;j<width1;j++)
        {
            result = *((array+i*3)+j);
            printf("%d ", result);        // added ;
        }
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    int myArray[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{5,4,3}};
    int height = 2;
    int width = 3;

    modifyArray( &myArray[0][0],height, width);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

1 2 3 5 4 3

If you want to modify the array, that is simply done with, for example

```
*((array+i*3)+j) = result;
```

Answer (score 1):

The cast to `( int ** )` is forcing myArray to be treated as an array of pointers to int.

That's not what it is - it's a single chunk of memory the compiler treats as a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: How could I correct it then? because just printing the entire array in the function myArray works fine. It is doing actual calculations that fails...

Answer (score 0):

The 2D array is compiled as a single dimensional array
See how the assembly generated is single array (between elements there is increment of 4 bytes)

```
int myArray[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{5,4,3}};
000000013F6510D4  mov         dword ptr [myArray],1  
000000013F6510DC  mov         dword ptr [rsp+2Ch],2  
000000013F6510E4  mov         dword ptr [rsp+30h],3  
000000013F6510EC  mov         dword ptr [rsp+34h],5  
000000013F6510F4  mov         dword ptr [rsp+38h],4  
000000013F6510FC  mov         dword ptr [rsp+3Ch],3
```

by doing reinterpret_cast (c-style cast) to int**- the memory layout being accessed is no more compatible- thus leading to accessing invalid memory